# Change loop to display items in order

Tags: loop

I am trying to customise a search query so that items returned are ordered in descending order.  I have managed to find the loop that generates the results....

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'listings',
    'meta_key' => '_ct_price',
    'orderby' => '_ct_price',
    'order' => 'DESC'
        );

// save the existing query
$existing_query_obj = $wp_query;

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
//$wp_query = new WP_Query( $search_values ); 

unset($search_values['post_type']);
unset($search_values['paged']);
unset($search_values['showposts']);                                

/** Prepare the title string by looping through all
the values we're going to query and put them together */
$search_params = ''; 
$loop = 0;
foreach ($search_values as $t => $s) {                                     
    if ($loop == 1) { 
        $search_params .= ', '; 
    } else {
        $loop = 1;
    }                              

    $term = get_term_by('slug',$s,$t);
    $name = $term->name;   
    $search_params .= '<strong>'. $name .'</strong>';                                    
}
```

As you can see I have added in an $args section with the ordering information in, it doesnt work currently, but if I comment out the following line..

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

And uncomment the following line....

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $search_values );
```

Then it does work but ignores the rest of the code, is there a way to add my $args onto the exiting query without breaking it?

Comment: Try `'orderby' => 'meta_value'`.

Comment: That works for me, but if I uncomment out the $wp_query = new WP_Query( $search_values ); line things still break.  Is there a way to include the $args with the $seach_values?

Comment: Yea, intercept the `posts_clauses` filter.

Comment: Im lost,  I cant seem to find much information on the posts_clause filter anywhere :(

Comment: **[Just search the site via Google](https://www.google.at/search?q=wordpress.stackexchange.com%3A+%22posts_clauses%22&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)**.  I know that there're tons of good answers about it. Some of them are from me, so I know they exist ;)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want `'orderby' => 'meta_value'` to sort by the specified `meta_key` or  `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'` if it's a numeric value.